# Function $f$, where $f(x)=f'(x)=F(x)$

Tags: calculus

I just wanted to ask whether there exists a function, apart from e^x or a multiple of e^x where its derivative and integral is itself. I'm not sure if e^x is the only function with this property, but if there are other functions, could you also please tell me what they are and how you find functions with this property. There might be a function involving complex numbers of just be really large but I'm not really sure whether another function of this type exists.

Thanks to anyone who answers in advance!

Comment: Every constant multiple of $e^x$ satisfies this property.

Comment: Are there any other functions that don't involve e^x at all?

Comment: The number $e$ is often defined in terms of the property that $(e^x)'=e^x$

Comment: @JC12 $f(x)=0$ for all $x$ also works. But that's a particular case of the general solution $f(x)=ke^x$ for some constant $k$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$f(x)=f'(x)$ implies $\frac d {dx} (e^{-x}f(x))=e^{-x}f'(x)-e^{-x}f(x)=0$ for all $x$ which implies that $e^{-x}f(x)=c$ for some constant $c$. Hence $f(x)=ce^{x}$.

Comment: Are there any other functions apart from a constant multiplied by e^x or e^-x?

Comment: I have **proved** that there are no other functions. @JC12

Comment: $ce^{-x}$ does not satisfy this property.

Comment: Thanks, I just read through it!